# PHP mysqldump returns no data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this script:

```
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h".DB_SERVER." -u".DB_USER." -p".DB_PASS." ".DB_NAME." | gzip > ".$filename;
system($command,$output);
echo $output;
```

It looks ok and it returns 0.

The file its producing contains:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.73, for pc-linux-gnu (i686)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: database_gourmet
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.73-cll

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

No tables no data, what gives?

Comment: echo out `$command`, cut&paste it to the command line, and see if it works there. if it doesn't, then it's not a php problem.

Comment: what is the extension of your file? .sql file or .zip

Comment: Change it to `gzip 2>&1 > ".$filename"` to capture warning messages, and echo the result of the `system()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PuTTY and echoing as Marc B suggested I found the problem, it was responded in this post:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84370/why-mysqldump-is-returning-with-error-1143-couldnt-execute-show-table-status

I resolved forcing the output -f:

```
$command = "mysqldump -f -h".DB_SERVER." -u".DB_USER." -p".DB_PASS." ".DB_NAME." | gzip > ".$filename;
```